# what to use instead of <xmp> or <pre>

Tags: html

I have a table where inputs are dynamically received from a server using json. The issue I am having is that sometimes data contains html codes which are supposed to be shown as it is. I can't change anything on database where I am receiving the data and when I use `<xmp>` or `<pre>` styles or doesn't apply anymore. Is there way to do it without using the two options above ?

Comment: You need to `htmlspechialchar()` the data prior to `json_encode()`ing it.

Comment: HTML is "supposed to be shown as is"… Does that mean that `"<b>Foo</b>"` is supposed to be displayed as <b>Foo</b>, not **Foo**?

Comment: I'm unclear what the connection between JSON, the database and HTML is here…

Comment: @deceze first option, I want it to be displayed as <b>Foo</b> and connection is just wanted to mention that I can't replace the < with "&lt;" for example.

Comment: Then you have a bit of a problem, since you'll need to output a valid HTML document, and for that you will have to replace those special characters with HTML entities…